# What is the purpose of connecting the collector of an NPN to the base of another NPN?

Tags: transistors, npn, transistor-array

In the circuit below, in the section inside the green circle,
it seems there's no purpose for connecting the NPN transistor's collector, to the base of the other NPN transistor on the right.

According to my understanding of how NPN transistors work, no current will flow through that base.

What is the purpose of connecting the collector of an NPN to the base of another NPN?

[The image is taken from a TI Hex inverter schematics]

[image]

Comment: @BrianDrummond if you'd refer me to the post that has an answer to this,  i would gladly remove my question

Comment: The linked question does answer it.

Comment: Duplicates are useful. They are not meant to be deleted. They help people find information. If you don't know what a TTL circuit is, you cannot ask "the right question", so your question will help other people having the same doubt.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you noticed, this is a TTL logic inverter.

When A is floating or pulled to high logic state, the leftmost transistor cannot operate as transistors normally are used. But its BC junction gives the Vcc through the 4kOhm resistor to the second transistor. When A is pulled to GND, it sucks off what was the base current of the 2nd transistor. Also stray and junction capacitance in the 2nd transistor get discharged effectively.

The benefit: Nothing in this (=inverter) case, simpler driving could as well be functional. But the principle makes easy to add more inputs for gate operations such as NAND. Inputs like this in a gate do not disturb each other. Of course the inverter also has got the same input for consistent logic-family wide input characteristics.